# VB.NET use Response.Flush() with IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: vb.net, iis, url-rewriting, response, outbound

I am trying to use `Response.Flush()` with IIS URL Rewrite outbound rules but I get the result on Chrome only after the end of the `vb.net` page executions.

Any ideas?

Comment: They have their own order of execution, as far as I know there is no way to modify them, can you share your purpose of doing this? Or you can do it differently.

Comment: I'm trying to use them together but not at the same time, the URL Rewrite I need to be able to update the browser cache on request while the flush obviously to force the partial write on chrome